# Regex to capture boolean variables that don't start with special words

Tags: regex

What I want to do is capturing boolean variables, which do not confirm to our standard in our Code and print an error message using Checkstyle.

```
// Things that should be matched

private boolean test;
private boolean        test;
private boolean mtest;

boolean test;
boolean     test;

// Things that should not be matched

private boolean isTest;
private boolean        isTest;
private boolean mIsTest;

boolean isTest;
boolean     isTest;

public boolean test() // No functions at all should be matched
```

The regex I am currently using is this one:

`(B|b)oolean[\s]+(?!(mC|c)an|(mS|s)hould|(mA|a)re|(mD|d)id|(mI|i)s|(mM|m)ust|(mH|h)as|(mW|w)as)`

Some things are already working and some aren't. [Here](http://www.regexr.com/3a31k) is a link to a site, which the test cases and the regex.

Does anybody know how to fix this weird case when spaces are applied before the variable and / or the case with functions?

Comment: Always mention the language/tool you're using. There's a big difference between PCRE and JS regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
(B|b)oolean\s+(?=\S)(?!(mC|c)an|(mS|s)hould|(mA|a)re|(mD|d)id|(mI|i)s|(mM|m)ust|(mH|h)as|(mW|w)as)(?!.+\(.*\))
```

I added `(?=\S)` to make sure `\s+` matches all spaces and `(?!.+\(.*\))` to exclude functions.

Answer (score 1):

Add a positive lookahead for a non-blank `(?=\S)` to stop backtracking that allows matching the last blank where you are expecting the first char of the variable name, and add another term to your negative look ahead to exclude a bracket anywhere ahead `...|.*\()`:

```
(B|b)oolean\s+(?!(mC|c)an|(mS|s)hould|(mA|a)re|(mD|d)id|(mI|i)s|(mM|m)ust|(mH|h)as|(mW|w)as|.*\()(?=\S)
```

See [live demo](http://rubular.com/r/Jiv43g5RWY)

Also note the removal of unnecessary square brackets around `\s`.

Comment: Thanks you were a little bit later so I accepted Sven answer.

Comment: @Niklas no problem! (it's tough having to thumb everything on a mobile :/ )

Answer (score 0):

```
(b)oolean\s+?[a-z]+?;
```

http://www.regexr.com/3a33d

Maybe I'm wrong, but it seem you are over complicating.

With this input all you have to do is ignore if the variable name have any uppercase.

Comment: The thing is that I especially want to check that the boolean has a certain prefix (is, can, are, did etc) to better distinguish them and make them more readable.